# batch FOR command - string together output of 2 dos commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

Trying to get this to work -

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b *.rar ^| findstr /i ^"par.*1^"' 'dir /s /b *.rar ^| findstr /v /i ^"part^"') DO (
winrar x "%%~i" "v:\unpack\"
)
```

It works fine with only the first 'dir /s /b *.rar', but I can't seem to chain them together. I know there are other syntaxes I can use, like *.rar and *.zip only but I have to search the dir output as shown. I tried adding a comma between the two dir commands but still makes no difference.

So...is this possible?

Comment: I deleted a part of my command re: findstr after the dir commands. I'll add it back in. I deleted it to make everything simpler but I guess it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working. Here is the cmd line -

```
'dir /s /b *.rar ^| findstr /i ^"par.*1^" ^& dir /s /b *.rar ^| findstr /v /i ^"part^"'
```